# How do I pass data from python to stdin and capture the stdout results?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stdin

I have LittleCMS transicc installed and running. From the command line I can run:

```
echo 100 0 0 50 0 0 | transicc  -i"*Lab" -o"*sRGB" -t3 -v0
```

and I get:

```
LittleCMS ColorSpace conversion calculator - 5.0 [LittleCMS 2.12]
Copyright (c) 1998-2020 Marti Maria Saguer. See COPYING file for details.
255.0000 255.0000 255.0000 
118.9133 118.9133 118.9133
```

so I know it's working. In Python 3.9.4 on my Mac I've tried:

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['transicc', '-i', '*Lab', '-o', '*sRGB', '-t3', '-v0']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, text=True, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout_data = p.communicate(input='100 0 0 50 0 0')[0]
print(stdout_data)
```

and stdout_data contains `''`. What am I missing? I assume it's something to do with the input, but I'm not sure how to pipe to it correctly to get results in stdout_data.

Comment: transicc  -i"*Lab" -o"*sRGB" -t3 -v0 - in your example -i and -o come in as one parameter . . . that is the -i and string together.  In your Python attempt, they will be two parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the help Frank. I changed it to `cmd = "transicc -i '*Lab' -o '*sRGB' -t3 -v0"` and it works now.